# Database backup Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Is there a way in Azure Resource manager to take a copy of an existing database? Currently I know there is a database import option, which points to a bacpac file in Blob Storage and creates a new database from that file, but the process to create the file is a manual one at this point. With that, what is the current process to create bacpacs and put them in Blob storage in an automated way through ARM?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to specify the createMode of your database in the ARM template. This is very undocumented stuff but I found this in the [REST api documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163685.aspx) and then just tried in the ARM template.

You can specify the properties "createMode" and "sourceDatabaseId".

I am not using this functionality because the sourceDatabaseId needs to be in the same subscription which was not the case with me. So i export the bacpac manually and then use an ARM template to import the bacpac (which also is undocumented but I commented the ARM template used here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-import/)